# How to make Cmake globally available

Tags: linux, cmake

I just installed Cmake from git clone wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.3.tar.gz in a new folder on a Linux server. The compilation worked but cmake command is not recognized from other paths. Should I copy the entire contents of cmake-2.8.0 folder to usr/local/bin? Or is the contents of bin folder that need to be copied?

Thanks

Comment: Don't install software from source, use your package manager. Failing that (only if you know well what you are doing) software built from sources in the usual GNU-ish way (configure, make all, make install) normally installs binaries to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I'm not the administrator but I have sudo rights. I'm not sure what I should try and the administrator is unresponsive.

Comment: So, this returns /opt/cmake/bin/cmake -version
cmake version 2.8.3. I just need to use cmake once to install another software. Is there a way to access it? thanks

Comment: You should install cmake from your package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux and other Unix-based systems, a common arrangement is to install packages to `/opt` and add relevant entries to the `PATH` environment variable to make them available. This is intended for packages not provided by the native package manager or distribution. By choosing an appropriate directory structure, this can be done in a way which also allows different versions to be installed simultaneously and the user can pick which one they want by adding the relevant directory to the `PATH`.

For the specific case of CMake asked about in the question, you can use a directory structure like `/opt/cmake/<version>` and then add the relevant `/opt/cmake/<version>/bin` directory to your `PATH` (e.g. `/opt/cmake/3.8.2/bin` for the 3.8.2 CMake release). You can even just [download](https://cmake.org/download/) the official pre-built CMake tarballs, unpack them and move the top level directory into the `/opt/cmake` area as the particular version you downloaded. I've used this successfully on Linux, MacOS and Solaris, as I'm sure have many others.

Note that once you've run CMake on a particular source tree, the `cmake` executable doesn't need to be on the `PATH` any more. If `cmake` needs to be re-run, the build will do so itself and it records the full path to the `cmake` executable in its own cache, so the `PATH` isn't even consulted (this is essential in ensuring the same version of CMake continues to be used for all builds regardless of the `PATH`, since `PATH` can change between login sessions, etc.). You would only need `cmake` on your `PATH` if you intend to invoke `cmake` manually or for the first time you run it on a source tree, but in both of these cases you can always just use the full path to the `cmake` executable if you preferred.

I should also add that the entire set of files provided in the CMake package are required, not just the `bin` directory. CMake makes extensive use of files in its other directories, such as the various modules it comes with. If you are building CMake from source, you may want to build the `package` target so you get a relocatable tarball or similar which will contain everything that should be included when you provide a CMake package on your system.

Answer (score 0):

After the build, use 'sudo make install'. This will make sure the correct libraries and binaries are copied to their proper places.

Usually this will install the binary to /usr/local/bin.

Make sure the PATH variable has this included.

Answer (score 0):

sudo make install did not copy to /usr/local/bin/ for some reason, so I copied the content of CMAKE /bin. to usr/local/bin an it worked.

cp –a bin/. /usr/local/bin/